I have a staked token in my wallet that seems to be increasing in amount over time. Is this a special type of contract?
I staked a token and the amount increases over time. Is this a special type of contract? Is it still considered an ERC-20?

Please share the token address at least.

https://ethplorer.io/address/0x961d4921e1718e633bac8ded88c4a1cae44b785a#
